# Corona sdk build v2013.2076 having error loading my game

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I am having this error after upgrading to v2013.2076. I didn't had this error message when working with pre version of corona sdk.

Why do I get this error message?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to import a module which can not be found. The proper way to import a modules is to use:

```
local sprite_module = require("modules.sprite")
```

where `modules` is a folder relative the `main.lua` and `sprite` is a .lua-file.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. I had to switch my system to Windows 8 64 bit and installed everything new (corona and zerobrane) and now corona no more finds the `sprite.lua` file.

I think I found the solution here:
http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/sprite/index.html

sprite.* is no more supported...

You can/have to use `display.newSprite()` to do this now.

Edit:
Now I found the definitive proof, its because the new grafic v2.0.
http://docs.coronalabs.com/guide/graphics/migration_v1.html 
(scrole to removed libraries...)

I also have problems with my joystick now... prob. this is related, too...

I am very unhappy about this, corona!